# How to reorder my model with actions

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to re-order my model with up and down buttons.
What's the ember way to perform these operations ?

Here is a jsbin:  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/haxegihaye/9/

Thank you for your help.

To be more clearer, I just want to select an item in my "model" which is an array, and just up or down this item. I think, I just need to change the index of the item in the array but I don't know how to perform this with ember ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sortProperties: propertyName` & `sortAscending: true/false`

Here is the [Demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mibude/1/edit?html,js,output)

I have modified your model to include `id` fields so that it is sorted by `id`.

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
      return [
        {id: 1, title: 'post 1'},
        {id: 2,title: 'post 2'},
        {id: 3,title: 'post 3'},
        {id: 4,title: 'post 4'},
        {id: 5,title: 'post 5'}
      ];
    }
});
```

And your controller will go like this -

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'post',



  selectedPost: null,

  actions: {
    up: function() {
      this.set('sortProperties', ['id']);
      this.set('sortAscending', true);

      if (this.get('selectedPost')) {
        var selectedPost = this.get('selectedPost');
        var index = this.get('model').lastIndexOf(selectedPost); 

        if (index > 1) {
          // up

        }
      }
    },
    down: function() {
     this.set('sortProperties', ['id']);
     this.set('sortAscending', false);

      if (this.get('selectedPost')) {
        var selectedPost = this.get('selectedPost');
        var index = this.get('model').lastIndexOf(selectedPost); 

        if (index < this.get('model.length')) {
          // down

        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry but I mispoke. I just want to up or down the selected item in the collection. So, up action on the post 4 change my model with this:

Post 1
Post 2
Post 4
Post 3
Post 5

Thanks

Comment: sorry could not understand the requirement. Please can you be more clearer ?